# How do I get custom keybinds to work in Visual Studio Community 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard, visual-studio-2019, settings

so I installed Visual Studio a week ago and tried to set up a few custom keybinds. Some worked but most didn't. Here I'll list a few examples:

1. `Ctrl+D` to delete a line (`Edit.LineDelete`). This is "duplicate line" by default. When I set "delete line" to Ctrl+D it says it will overwrite the keybind for "duplicate line" but it doesn't. When I go back to the setting is says duplicate line has no keybind and delete line is Ctrl+D however when I press Ctrl+D in the editor (even after a restart) it'll just duplicate the line.
2. `Ctrl+Shift+Down/Up` to move the selected line(s) down/up (`Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp/Down`). Here it says it unbound the default keybind and now this action is bound to whatever I set up. However, when I select something (or even if I just put my cursor somewhere) and press Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down it'll select some random buttons outside of the actual editor window.

(This happens no matter which preset I start with.)

I also tried installing VSTricks and SublimeVS in hopes of getting that fixed but VSTricks is bugged (i.e. it won't even apply new settings) and SublimeVS just changed some defaults and that's it.

So how do I set up actually working keybinds? So far this IDE's been nothing but a nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got help from elsewhere: You need to set the keybind to "Text Editor" scope instead of "Global" since global scopes seem to be overwritten by more specified ones.